# Swift: URLSession or URLRequest adds extra headers. How to omit them?

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlrequest, urlsession

I have set up a local express app to monitor requests made by my iOS app and found it odd that when printing the headers, one entry is

`'accept-language': 'en-US,de;q=0.9'`

because I did not set any specific headers at all. I tried to set nil for that header like

```
var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "http://localhost:3000/iosnativereq")!)
request.setValue(nil, forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept-Language") //also tried lower case

let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
    print(data, response, error)
}

task.resume()
```

however the requests my server gets still include the field. I would prefer having control over what headers to be sent, how can I make iOS not add these headers (or at least be able to remove them before actually performing the task)

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39627616/preventing-nsurlsession-default-http-headers) might be informative (although probably not what you want to hear :)).

Comment: I don't think you can remove default headers even if you try to use a custom URLSession. But did you try to set it to `*` (i.e. `Accept-Language: *` so that it can accept any language? If that doesn't work, and you really must get rid of them... don't use URLSession is the only answer unfortunately...

Comment: Thank you for you guys' comments. I'm not running into specific issues with the headers (yet), I just found it odd that they get added regardless of what I tried.

Comment: It's possible to remove the value, although not the key (eg. `"Accept-Language": ""`).